# Laravel placing variable into @lang()

Tags: php, laravel

```
@lang('bonus.foo')
@lang('bonus.{{$data["ruleclass"]}}') <-- $data["ruleclass"]
```

I need to put variable into @lang in laravel, the variable can be conditional, is anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: what about `@lang('bonus.' . $data["ruleclass"])` ?

Comment: wow that works! can u put on answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using the traditional php concatenating way ,

```
@lang('bonus.' . $data["ruleclass"])
```